# How to embed google map to show list of connected locations in iOS APP & Android App

Tags: android, iphone, google-maps, google-maps-api-2, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am developing small app which take list of co-ordinates(longitude and latitudes) and plots the same in map view.

I also want to add some message for each location. Could anyone let me know if there is tutorial to complete this?

I already got API tokens in order to access googple map api.

Comment: i would like to bring up map as well. Please let me know if there is tutorial.

Comment: in iphone or android?

Comment: currently iPhone... can I make use of web content? Can I form a url and open in next view adding web content? please suggest..

Comment: from where are u getting lat long

Comment: I get them based on zip code (USA).